# Refer properties in serverless yaml

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In documentation

> https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

I find there are a couple of places where certain properties or variables are referred to as something like `$.stageVariables`,`$.time`,`$.userIdentity.type`, etc. It is kind of confusing to me about their meanings. Is there any documentation somewhere around this kind of variables? I only find the variable related documentation here

> https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#referencing-serverless-core-variables

which didn't cover anything on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the documentation here is poor and I can't find a definitive guide, but I can point you in the right direction.

These aren't serverless variables, they're AWS-made configuration for CloudWatch filtering.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html